# Reference Global Constants In Core Data? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, data-structures

I'm working on a reference app that has a lot of data.

I currently have this data hardcoded as a global properties as a struct. However, there are other user input properties I'd like to attach and persist to this struct.

Is there a way to keep the reference data in the struct/global constant, and point to it in Core Data to manage these other properties?

For example:

```
let myStruct = MyStruct(...)
```

And then in Core Data, have an entity that looks something like:

```
Entity: MyData:

myStruct: ??? (Somehow reference the struct above - String with the constant name?)
myBool1: Bool
myBool2: Bool
myString: String
etc
```

Comment: A property in MyStruct of type MyData?

Comment: Hello. I don’t want to save the struct into Core Data, the struct is a global constant. I want to be able to reference the struct constant from within core data and other user input properties if possible.

Comment: Ok your text says something different than your code (and comment) so I misunderstood. Anyway it doesn’t make sense to store constant data in core data. Since it is constant and global it is immutable data that you always has access to so there is no need to persist it or even hold a reference to it.

Comment: Sorry for the miss understanding. How else can you reference that data then in combination with user input then? For example, combing the struct with a __var isFavorite: Bool__? What I’m trying to figure out how how to connect the global constant with the user actions.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t understand what you mean.

Comment: No worries.  - essentially I’m working on a reference app. It contains a lot of data for different materials. But these materials all also be mixed together to form different ‘recipes’. - Basically these materials are all of the same struct type and are global constants. - However, there’s other things I need to associate with these materials that can different from user to user. For example, if the material is one of their favorites. Or the cost for the material. - The structs are fairly large. And I have no real experience with Core Data. So I’m trying to figure out if there’s a way...

Comment: A way that I can leave the data alone and have a way to connect it other data that will be saved by the user inside of core data.